# sodu: command not found

Tags: 14.04

I was in the middle of installing several apps using the `sodu apt-get install` command when all of a sudden `sodu` started producing the error `sodu:command not found`. What is going on?

> **Editor's note:** The spelling of the command is as he typed it.

Comment: You probably meant `sudo` instead of `sodu`

Comment: @Pandya That's why I added the editor's note thingy...

Comment: @Pandya Fixed...

Comment: Ask from himself: Did you type "sodu" or "sudo"?

Answer (score 3):

As hamatti stated, you misspelled `sudo` as `sodu`.

The correct command is `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`.